# Richfaces 4.x and Jquery latest conflicts

Tags: jquery, jsf, richfaces

I have set of html files which uses latest jquery library and I am going to convert these files into xhtmls and using rich faces for ajax functionality. But it seems richfaces jquery is getting conflicted with my latest jquery. How to separate it out? I cannot convert my Jquery code by writing Jquery.noconfilct() because it is very huge. I want to have the pages to treat richfaces jquery separately from the actual jquery library.

Comment: What is the conflict? What error is happening? Where is the error happening? What is causing the error?

Comment: @KevinB looks like you're new to RichFaces, and OP is using RF 4.x, maybe 4.2 (lates release) or 4.3 (the next milestone). In any case, there is always conflicts when you want to add an external jQuery library to these kind of projects.

Comment: Here is a good start point for your needs: [Tips and tricks on jQuery and RichFaces](http://jee-bpel-soa.blogspot.com/2009/04/tips-and-tricks-on-jquery-and-richfaces.html). In case you have more problems, you should post a question in [JBoss RichFaces Forum](https://community.jboss.org/en/richfaces/dev?view=discussions). Remember that stackoverflow is not a site to get support of any product.

Comment: Right, i am new to RichFaces, but from what i've read it does come with jQuery pre-installed, and a different version based on what version of RichFaces you are using, correct? In that case, it really wouldn't make sense to try to include the latest and greatest jQuery version if it's only 1.8.0 vs 1.7.2 unless it would make a significant difference in your code.

Comment: Actually, I am using a template for my UI which uses huge jquery and css to get the rich look and feel for the pages and I am just trying to add jsf and richfaces functionality for those pages. But wherever I add ajax capabilities to buttons, input fields they are not behaving as expected. Even I was trying to display validation messages with ajax requests (means, immediately after entering the input) which are not working as expected. I have found several other issues too.